# Abbreviated URLs in comments render &hellip; instead of …

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

Well, what the title says. If I post an URL in a comment, it gets shortened, and the ellipsis is shown by `…`. Or at least, should be, because it shows up as `&hellip;`.

Comment: Demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment.